# From lodash debounce to angular 6 reactive

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, reactive-programming

I have a wiered question and sorry if it's a duplication of some answer (however I still can't find solution for my problem).

The thing is I'm remaking old Angular JS app to Angular 6 app. And I have debouncing function in old app:

```
var debouncing = _.debounce(changeValue, 10000);

function changeValue() {
    // some increment stuff for example
}

debouncing();
```

Now I need to rewrite it to function without lodash. At first I wanted to use `setTimeout` but then I found [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html). But it could be applied only for subjects. But my `changeValue` is a simple function.

How can I make debounce avoiding of using lodash in terms of Angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's convert your function into an observable:

```
const changeValue$ = defer(() => of(changeValue()));
```

Then, let's apply `debounceTime`:

```
changeValue$.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(...);
```